# how does WebSocketChannel warns that it disconnected?

Tags: dart, dart-2

I am using WebSocketChannel as a socket server:

```
var handler = webSocketHandler((WebSocketChannel webSocket) async {
}
```

How can I know when the webSocket above gets disconnected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to listen on the channel stream and intercept the close event with the `onDone` callback.

`closeCode` and `closeReason` properties give you details about the close.

```
webSocketHandler((channel) {
  channel.stream.listen((data) {
    channel.sink.add('Echo: $data');
  },
  onDone: () {
    print('socket closed: reason=[${channel.closeReason}], code:[${channel.closeCode}]');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Even thought there is a correct answer to this thread, I ended up using another package for handling socket connections: 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/socket_io